# how to add values in a dictionary using for loop?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains a list `capex` in which there is one value. The basic structure of that dictionary is:

```
outputDic = {
    "capex": [{
                "value": 450000,
                "start": 5,
                "year": 10
     }]
}
```

`value`, `start`, and `year` are just the random numbers but there is `decider` variable which will basically decide how many values will be there in the list. So let just say if `decider` is 2 then there will two values and if it is 3 then there will be three values in the list and so on.My approach:

```
outputDic = {
    "capex": [{
               "value": 450000,
               "start": 5,
               "year": 10
           }]
}

decider = 2
for i in range(1, decider):
    outputDic['capex'][i]['value'+str(i)] = 40*i
    outputDic['capex'][i]['start'+str(i)] = 20*i
    outputDic['capex'][i]['year'+str(i)] = 10*i
    
print(outputDic)
```

It gives an error of `List out of index` and that may be because there is only one element in the list. My expected output is:

```py
decider = 2
outputDic = {
    "capex": [
        {
            "value": 40,
            "start": 20,
            "year": 10
        },
        {
            "value": 80,
            "start": 40,
            "year": 20
        }
    ]
}
Can anyone please help?
```

Comment: capex is a list, you're trying to assign to an index that does not exist which is why you get an error. Try appending a dictonnary directly to the list.

Comment: "and that may be because there is only one element in the list" yes, exactly. Are you asking how to add items *to a list?*

Comment: yes I am asking to add value, start and year acc to decider

Comment: As you can see in the expected output section where I explained if the decider is 2 the there will be two values in the Capex list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do that. Use `append` to add new items to the list.

```
outputDic = {
        "capex": []
}
decider = 2
for i in range(decider):
    outputDic['capex'].append(
        {
            'value' : 40*i, 
            'start': 20*i, 
            'year':10*i
        }
    )

print(outputDic)
```

The output is:

```
{'capex': [{'value': 0, 'start': 0, 'year': 0}, 
           {'value': 40, 'start': 20, 'year': 10}]}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply but there is one problem with this. Its not changing the default value. In the original dic the value, start and year remain same

Comment: Would you like the first entry in the dict to change as well, according to the same logic?

Comment: ahh, I am sorry but there is still one small issue with this. the name of the value, start and year should remain the same. Can we do that ? I mean it should be value, start and year just, not value0, start0, year0